# How to refresh a view after data is received in Odoo 11/12

Tags: view, refresh, odoo

Is there a better way to do this?

In my view I added this to the record view.xml:

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
  <tree string="Test View" js_class="test_view">
    <field name="testField" />
  </tree>
</field>
```

I have a template file template.xml that I referenced the **manifest.py**

```
<xpath>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/<mymodule>/static/src/js/<mymodule>.js"> 
  </script>
</xpath>
```

Added this function to my model:

```
@api.model
def generate_data(self):
  # do stuff on database
  pass
```

I have this in my module controller:

```
class Reports(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/test/refresh', type='json', auth="user")
    def refresh(self):
        return request.env['model.name'].generate_data()
```

I then extended the base ListView in the above mentioned .js:

```
odoo.define('<mymodule>.updateview, function (require) {

  var view_registery = require('web.view_registry');
  var ListController = require('web.ListController');
  var ListView = require('web.ListView');

  var TestListController = ListController.extend({
    init: function () {
      this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var self = this;
            this._rpc({
                route: '/test/refresh'
            }).then(function() {
                self.reload();
            });

    }
  });


  var ReportListView = ListView.extend({
      config: _.extend({}, ListView.prototype.config, {
          Controller: TestListController 
       }),
   });
  view_registery.add('test_view')
});
```

It all works well on loading the page. Is there a better way that Odoo recommends? Or maybe this can help someone else.

Comment: What data do you want generate into a record? Is there no way to use Odoo's default features (like default values) to achieve your requirements?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? It would be easier to help if we know what your goal is.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could use an odoo client action to reload the view as return of your python function:

```
@api.model
def generate_data(self):
  # do stuff on database
  (...)
  return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.client',
    'tag': 'reload',
  }
```